What is に doing here?
Yet yet another question about 16 bit sensation chapter 3 column:

本作で『同級生』について書いているが、この大ヒットは、エロゲーから美少女ゲームへの転換を大きく進めたと言える。それはつまり、「エロがメインで、そのための存在としてのヒロイン」から、「ヒロインと主人公との関係性や感情、物語を紡ぐことによってたどり着く恋愛描写、そしてエロ」とゲーム内の序列が転換したことに他ならない。つまりヒロインはエロの道具(失礼)ではなく、恋愛対象でドラマの主人公となり、その結果として、より深いキャラクター性を持つことになる。それが何を生んだか一一一ヒロインがよりかわいくなったのだ。これが後の「萌え」につながっていくのは、想像に難くないだろう。そしてそうした作品の多くは「エロの舞台」としてではなく、ヒロインをより魅力的に描くために18禁である必要があり、エロシーンもそのひとつであるというものだった。こうした転換の大本のひとつに「沙織事件」の影響がある。1991年、未成年者による『沙織-美少女達の館-』万引き事件が発生。この事件をきっかけに、アダルトゲームの購入に年齢規制がないことが問題視され、厳しい目が向けられることとなり、当該作品を含めた数作品が摘発の対象となった(本作でも描かれているように、ソフ倫設立の要因のひとつともなった)。この事件以降、過激なエロさを競うようなゲーム作り一辺倒から脱却し、新たな魅力を発掘する必要が出てきた。そうした市場状況に、新たなゲームを生み出す新進気鋭のクリエイターの登場というタイミングが重なった結果が、美少女ゲームジャンルの多様性につながったと言えるだろう(これらの詳細については巻末コラムにまとめたいと思う)。まさに「塞翁が馬」。ここから美少女ゲームは大きくブレイクし、バブルとも呼べる状況へと突入していく。

I am bit uncertain with に after そうした市場状況. It seems like the basic structure is AにBが重なった結果 (result of B overlapping with A in terms of time, i.e. result of B happening at the same time as A) where A is そうした市場状況 and B is 新たなゲームを生み出す新進気鋭のクリエイターの登場というタイミング. Is that correct?

Yes, you're perfectly correct. AにBが重なる is the same as BがAに重なる and means B overlaps with A.
